# Angular directive for changing image source in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table, in the row, the element is an image

Upon hover it changes colour.

1) I am new to Angular, and I am not sure how to write a directive to dynamically change the image to a custom one depending on which table row has been hovered on. So for example if there are 5 table row, the hover colour will be different depending on which one has been hovered over.

Here is my table code:

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">
                            <span></span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-xs-8" ng-click="sort('firstName')">
                            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='firstName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">
                            <span></span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-click="showModal($event, user.emailAddress)" dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">
                        <td>
                            <!--img class="round" src="/images/profile-placeholder.jpg" width="50" height="50">
                                </img> -->
                                <img class="round" src={{user.profileImageUrl}} width="50" height="50"></img>
                        </td>
                        <!-- <td><img src={ {user.profileImageUrl}} width="100" height="100"></img></td> -->
                        <td>
                            <div style="padding-top:1em"><span>{{user.firstName}}</span>
                                <br>{{user.lastName}}
                                <br>{{user.profession}}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style="padding-top:1em">
                                <img src="images/arrow-right-pink.png" width="50" height="50"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('hoverBgImage',function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            elm.bind('mouseenter',function(){
]
            });
            elm.bind('mouseleave',function(){
            })
        }
    };
});
```

In my directive I am not sure how to only select and apply changes to the image element for the row I have hovered over.

I can do this

> $('img').image = 'new path'

in the mouse enter function but that will affect all images.

How can I do this, thanks.

Comment: proper angular way would be to change model data and have the model data manage the `ng-src` of image. You could do this all with built in directives also `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave`

Comment: The only problem with that approach is that I will be unable to select elements of the DOM where ng-mouseenter is not attached without using a directive.